# How to run .bash file in Mac?

Tags: bash, macos

```
I want to execute 
Path : "/Users/Trans/Downloads/solr-6.1.0"
Command: "bin/solr start -p 8983"
and 
Path : " /Users/Trans/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.12.0/bin"
Command: "./activemq console"
```

To make it executable on click I create one .command file 
having

```
 !#/bin/bash
 "/Users/Trans/Downloads/solr-6.1.0" bin/solr start -p 8983
 "/Users/Trans/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.12.0/bin" ./activemq console
```

> Given chmode +x permissions to it
>   But something seems to be wrong, Code is not getting executed.

My aim is to create one batch/bash file on double clicking on it should open terminal and execute both commands or more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shebang begins with `#!` not `!#`

```
#!/bin/bash

# verbose mode ( or -v in shebang )
set -v

cd "/Users/Trans/Downloads/solr-6.1.0" && bin/solr start -p 8983
echo "press a key to continue"
read -n1

cd "/Users/Trans/Downloads/apache-activemq-5.12.0/bin" && ./activemq console
echo "press a key to continue"
read -n1
```